# Do an arithmetic left shift of x by n bits (C)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Me and my group of 4 people are both completely blanking on how to correctly do an arithmetic left shift of an int x, by an amount of n bits.

It is a for a homework problem on bit manipulation for C. We are not allowed to use loops, if statements, or any operations over 15. I've attached the code given below. Also, the simple solution x << n does not work, even though I'm sure we are missing something obvious. If anyone could help or provide guidance, it would be much appreciated.

```
    /* 
    * arithLeftShift - Do an arithmetic left shift of x by n bits.
    *   Can assume that 0 <= n <= 31
    *   Examples: arithLeftShift(0x87654321,4) = 0xF6543218
    *   Legal ops: ~ & ^ | + << >> !
    *   Max ops: 15
    *   Rating: 3
    */
    int arithLeftShift(int x, int n) {
   return 0;
   }
```

Current error message:

```
Test arithLeftShift(-2147483648[0x80000000],1[0x1]) failed...
...Gives 0[0x0]. Should be -2147483648[0x80000000
```

Comment: `return 0` Which bit do you think is doing a shift?

Comment: "arithLeftShift(0x87654321,4) = 0xF6543218" makes no sense at all. You must have some additional description

Comment: That’s just the question format. If statements and loops are outlawed but I know how those would work. Basically, we tried a couple variations of x << n, then returning x, either as a new int or keeping x as the variable.

Comment: @4386427, sorry dude but that’s all our instructor gave us. If you search for bits.c the top GitHub results will have the full instructions but they aren’t really relevant.

Comment: left shift always inserts 0s. There are no separate arithmetic and logical shifts like in case of right shift

Comment: @flunky2k If this is all your instruction gave you, you need to go back to the instructor and ask for further description of what the function is supposed to do. In C programming left shift of a negative integer is undefined behavior. Arithmetic left shift should doesn't differ. It requires the zeros are shifted in at least significant bit. The example you gave doesn't do that. So it's unclear what the function is supposed to do. It could look like a cyclic shift with the requirement that the sign bit (i.e. most significant bit) shall keep its value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It is not arithmetic left shift.It's your arithLeftShift with your sign bit needn't a left shift. And the high bits needed to be shifted to the low position, It looks like a cycle shift.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    arithLeftShift(0x87654321,4);
}
int arithLeftShift(int x,int n)
{
    int temp,i;  //define two auto variables,
    i=x>>(32-n);//i for x's high n bits.
    temp=x<<n;//temp for x left shift n bits

    if(x>0)//sign bit is 0,
    {
        x=temp+i;
        x=x>0?x:x^0x80000000;//change the x sign bit is 0;
    }
    else
    {//when you do right shift, there will be different with different compliers and your x.
        if(i>0){//This means when you do right shift, 0 be inserted into high bits.
        x=temp+i;
        }
        else
        {
          i=(0x80000000>>(32-n));
          x=temp+i;
        }
        x=x>0?~(x^(~0x80000000)):x;//change the x sign bit is 1
        printf("%x\n",x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ask seems to be to "Rotate" the integer "Left", "n" number of times but retain the "Sign Bit"(MSB) if set.

One solution would be......

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#define INT_BITS 32  

int arithLeftShift(int x, int n) {
  int res;
  res = (x << n | (x >> (INT_BITS - n) & ~(~0 << n))) | x & (~0 << (INT_BITS - 1));
  return res;
}

int main(){

  int x = 0x87654321;
  int n = 4;

  printf("0x%x\n",arithLeftShift(x,n));

}
```

Explanation:

- (x << n)

Left shift x, n times - the last n bits are zero.

(x >> (INT_BITS - n) & ~(~0 << n))

Right shift x (INT_BITS - n) times to put the first n bits at the correct position and "AND" it with ~(~0 << n) to set the upper bits to zero.This will take care of "sign extension", if any.

(x << n | (x >> (INT_BITS - n) & ~(~0 << n)))

"OR" them to perform the "Rotate Left" operation.

- x & (~0 << (INT_BITS - 1)

Left shift "-1", 31 times and "AND" it with x to check if the MSB of x is set.

(x << n | (x >> (INT_BITS - n) & ~(~0 << n))) | x & (~0 << (INT_BITS - 1))

Finally "OR" the above expressions to get your answer.